# Best practices to segment people and attributes for advertising database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse

we have a database where we store people some attributes per person in the following tables:

```
people (id, name, email, phone)
people_attributes (id, person_id, attribute_name, attribute_value)
people_location (id, person_id, location_id) (links to locations table)
people_devices (id, person_id, device_id)
people_metrics (id, person_id, metric_type, value) -- very very large table
```

I need to be able to run queries like this one:

```
Get all people that  ( 
    live in Moscow 
    OR  
    live in Athens 
    OR  
    live in Istanbul 
    OR 
    live in San Francisco ) 
AND 
have an iPhone 
AND ( EITHER
          have at least one metric of type X
          OR
          have at least one metric of type Y )
```

How would you go about achieving that?

Currently using an SQL Server 2012 which takes minutes for the above query. Posting the query itself here is irrelevant as I am looking for best practices to achieve the above which may mean a re-architecture / re-engineering

There is budget to upgrade to SQL Server 2014 or switch to other databases or cloud offerings.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if anyone else would agree, but without seeing the query, it's hard to tell you why your query is taking a long time. However, have you looked at the STATS IO to see which table is getting most of the reads? Also, have you looked at the actual execution plan to see where the est # of rows differs from the actual? And finally, have you broken the query into multiple steps (temp or staging tables)? I have found sometimes that helps in multiple join tables.

Comment: It's taking all of the CPU. And it's hard to index the relevant tables cause some criteria may not be city IS London, but it often is city STARTS WITH 'San' OR city ENDS WITH 'XYZ' so its really hard to index the tables.

Comment: As you said the query is created in different steps and is broken into components. Each thing puts the results in temp tables

Comment: Well that is different than you listed in your original question :) LIKE statements are notoriously bad, especially if the wildcard is in the middle or the front of the search string. Think of it this way, lets say you are looking for "Chris Woods" in the phone book. You remember my first name is Chris, but you forget my last name. The phone book is listed in an alphabetical sort order (read index) "Lastname, Firstname". So to search for name like '%Chris' means SQL needs to scan through the whole entire document because you want to return "Adams, Chris", "Martin, Chris", and "Woods, Chris".

Comment: But if you knew my last name, searching name like "Woods%", then SQL would be able to utilize that index and go directly to that part of the index (through the b tree). I understand it may be using all the CPU, but you still need to look at the STATS IO and also the est/actual row counts to help figure out what the best approach is IF you can't avoid the front/middle wildcard scenario.

Comment: I would be curious how and why you are breaking it up. Seeing the query helps speed up answers on here :)